# Im trying to make items in game and sometimes its not working the way I think it would

Tags: dota-2

so im trying to make Aghanim's Scepter as wraith king and I have all 4 items. Then i try to click the buy thing on Aghanim's Scepter in the store and it says I need 4200 more gold, do I need to have all 4200 gold at one time to but it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all the components for an item, they will automatically merge when they're in the same inventory, which could be your hero's or the courier's. It says you need 4200 more gold because it assumes you're trying to buy a second one, since you already have all the components for the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was trying to merge them from the couriors and my inventory, thank you very much, how do I add to your reputation or such?

Comment: @Nathan If the answer was useful, you can click the up arrow next to it to upvote it, and if it was the most useful for solving your problem, you can click the checkmark to mark it as accepted.